# Fourier series... delta notation

Tags: notation, fourier-series

I'm going through the answer to a Fourier series question and have come across some notation which I haven't seen before.

The question is to represent the periodic function

$$f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
-1 - \sin(x) & : - \pi < x \le 0\\
1 - \sin(x) & : 0 < x \le \pi
\end{array}
\right.$$

(with the period $2\pi$) as a Fourier series.

I'm finding only the $b_{n}$ terms since it is clearly an odd function.

It quickly reduces to

$$ b_{n} = \frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^{\pi}{\sin(nx)}\,dx - \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{\sin(x) \cdot \sin(nx)}\,dx
$$

and the next line in the answer is:

$$ = \bigg[-\frac{2}{n\pi} \cos(nx)\bigg]^{\pi}_{0} - \delta_{m1}$$

I can see how the first integral reduces to the first part — it's just the delta that I've not seen before.

I tried to solve the second integral myself, using trig rules, and I got

$$ - \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{\sin(x) \cdot \sin(nx)}\,dx =- \frac{2\sin(n \pi)}{\pi(-1 + n^2)}$$

(ie. this should be the second 'half' of my $b_n$).

---

I'm not sure how to reduce this to the (correct) answer of

$$ f(x) = \sum_{0}^{\infty} \frac{2}{n\pi} (1 − (−1)^n) \sin(nx) - \sin(x) $$

The part I'm struggling with is how to get from the second 'half' of my $b_n$ to the $-\sin(x)$ term. Perhaps knowing what the $\delta$ is will help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $\delta_{ml}$ is shorthand notation for the following: if $m=l$, then $\delta_{ml} = 1$; if $m\neq l$, then $\delta_{ml} = 0$. Note that if $n\neq 1$, then $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin(x)\sin(nx)\,dx = 0$ which is most easily verified by using complex exponentials. If however $n=1$, then you're integrating $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \sin(x)^2\,dx$ (which is not zero). Does this help?

Comment: Ah, I'd seen this function before. I can't see why this would work here though. Firstly, what is $m$ in this context? Are we not finding different values of $b_n$? Secondly, I can't see how my solution for the second 'half' will ever equal 1. Isn't it 0 for all natural $n$ due to the numerator? Finally, once I've got this delta, how do I get to the final solution?

Comment: Your edit has helped, thanks. Should the subscript on the delta be $n1$ rather than $m1$ then?

Comment: I used $m$ and $l$ as dummy variables just to give you an idea of what the Dirac delta $\delta_{ml}$ does in general since it shows up a lot in Fourier analysis. In your case, it is definitely $\delta_{n1}$.

Comment: A typo on the mark scheme has at least contributed to my confusion then! Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you give me any pointers on the method to verify that $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin(x)\sin(nx)\,dx = 0$ for $n \neq 1$?

Comment: The way I like best is using complex exponentials but you can use reduction formulae to get a general expression for $\int \sin(nx)\sin(mx)\,dx$. Meaning.. do integration by parts twice.

Comment: " Isn't it 0 for all natural n due to the numerator?" When $n=1$ the denominator also vanishes. At some point you divided by $n^2-1$; that step was invalid when $n=1$.